# Creating a box framework for inside the formula environment

Tags: math-mode, boxes

For a list of things to be used inside the formula environment, I want to create boxes stacked over each other. I basically want to write

```
$$ A := "Box with lines like 'A is a number', 'A is bigger than 3',... " $$
```

What I come up with is is

```
\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{\stackrel{\fbox{$#1$}}{\fbox{$#2$}}}
```

but it pretty much sucks when it comes to what I really want. It's only two boxes and they don't even touch each other. Their length depends on the content. It should look more like a shelf. The length of all boxes should fit (the height might depend on the content). Also, the box should be oriented such that the := is in the vertical center. But if I want to use my construction for more than two boxes I have to do stupid things like

```
\mybox{statement 1}{\mybox{and statement 2}{statement 3}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about a simple tabular?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colonequals}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  A \colonequals
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    statement 1\\\hline
    and statement 2\\\hline
    statement 3\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image: Boxes via tabular]

Edit: Making a n-ary function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colonequals}

\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\boxes}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \toks@={%
      \begin{tabular}{|c|}%
      \hline
    }%
    \comma@parse{#1}\box@entry
    \the\toks@
    \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\box@entry}[1]{%
  \toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@
    #1\tabularnewline
    \hline
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  A \colonequals
  \boxes{
    statement 1,
    and statement 2,
    {statement 3, 4 and 5},% comma needs to be protected by braces
    another statement,
  }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image: Boxes with n-ary function]

The contents of the tabular is first written in a token register. That avoids trouble
with cell groups and empty lines at the end.

Edit: Further reading:

- Token registers: Victor Eijkhout, **TeX by Topic**, **Chapter 14: Token lists**,
  [CTAN:info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf)
- Package documentation of `kvsetkeys`, **Section 1.7: Comma separated lists**, [CTAN:macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.pdf)

Comment: Looks good, do you see a possibility of making it an n-ary function?

Comment: Cool, could you please elaborate a bit on that. It seems tha \comma@parse command takes the argument apart by its comma seperations and on each you somehow apply \box@entry by saving it with \toks@ as running variable. But What is \the and how does the recursion work?